How to build a Capacitor FullStack App from different backend/frontend project?
Disclaimer : I'm more a DevOps / Sysadmin than a developer so this might be a dumb question...
I'm creating my first app (from end to end) but in order to learn I'm not going the most straightforward way...
I have created a monorepo (Yarn + Turborepo) whose structure is like that :
.
├── README.md
├── apps
│   ├── backends
│   │   ├── database
│   │   ├── expressjs
│   │   └── nestjs
│   └── frontends
│       └── react-mui
│       └── vuejs
├── package.json
├── turbo.json
└── yarn.lock

I can use any combination of backend/frontend from those folders. ie: I can run my app using react and express or react and nest or vue and express or vue and nest. Both backends use data from the apps/backends/databases folder (where sits few sqlite databases). The idea was just to test as many (not much so far) JS frameworks as possible.
Now, I would like to create native Apps (mobile and desktop) with any combination of backend/frontend as stated above. I intended to do so with Ionic Capacitor (just by using the Capacitor runtime - no Ionic SDK involved there, at least yet) but I have only managed to build a 'frontend' version of my app so far (convert the react app to iOS).
After days of searching the web I'm still wondering how to transform one of my full web app into a native one (with my project configuration) ? Is it even possible ? (I'm starting to think I took the problem the wrong way)
Thanks for any help.
